# How to click on Accept button using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to click on the cookie accept button but it doesn't work. Can someone help me?

https://www.forbes.com/consent/?toURL=https://www.forbes.com/billionaires

```
driver.get('https://www.forbes.com/consent/toURL=https://www.forbes.com/billionaires') 
driver.implicitly_wait(15) buttonAccept =  driver.find_element_by_class_name("call") driver.implicitly_wait(5)
buttonAccept.click()
```

If I try to find element by xpath, I get this error:

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[8]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/a[1]"}

EDIT:
I think is a problem with iframe, but I don't know how to solve it. I think i need to "driver.switch_to_frame"

Answer (score 1):

This is not a valid url. But can you please try the following in your code?

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.forbes.com/consent/toURL=https://www.forbes.com/billionaires')
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Accept']"))).click()
```

Comment: try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Accept']")))
    element.click()
finally:
    driver.quit()

Comment: raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Answer (score 1):

The cookie consent manager pop-up has an `iframe`s embedded into it, so you would need to switch to it first and only afterwards to click the button.

```
    iframe_elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('iframe[title="TrustArc Cookie Consent Manager"')
    driver.switch_to.frame(iframe_elem)
    accept_btn = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.call')
    accept_btn.click()
```

Comment: Thank you!!!!! This is working, haha :) I tried this: driver.switch_to.frame("pop-frame0665201962429294") where pop-.... is the id of the iframe but this didn't work. Mersi ba, m-ai salvat

Comment: Glad to hear. I avoided using the `id` because there is a possibility that it is a dynamic one, so it won't work. Please consider accepting it as an answer if it solved your issue. Cu placere